# Room with Kitchenette, Who Does the Dishes?

Tags: hotels, services

Got a room in a guest house with a kitchenette. The owner said she would do the cleaning, but does this usually include doing the dishes? Even if I've been in a room with a kitchenette before, I had never used one!

**Who is normally expected to wash the dishes for places fitted with a kitchenette?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you renting it using Airbnb or some like that?
If yes, I believe it is polite you clean the dishes that you have used.

On the other hand, if you are in a hotel, I believe the hotel will have people to do these tasks.

Comment: No, it's not AirBnB, its a normal guest house booked from Booking.com. I've also had kitchenettes in hotels from Booking.com, Agoda and Expedia, but I still don't know who would have done this dishes. Some of these are upcoming stays, so it would be great to know!

Comment: I am assuming that it is hotel or some like that. If yes, I believe you do not need to clean the dishes.

Comment: Indeed, if there is room cleaning service, it includes the dishes. I left dirty dishes two days in a row and they were washed at the same time the room was cleaned I expect that AirBnB does not offer cleaning services, so one has to do it themselves, including doing the beds.

Answer (score 3):

In general, try to leave the place cleaner than you got it.

Do the dishes, clean up the counter area, empty the fridge, put out the trash/recycle.

If it is a kitchenette in a hotel room, you could leave the dishes to be done by the hotel staff; if it is in a guest house, I'd clean it.

Answer (score 1):

Guests staying in a kitchenette are provided with dish cloth ,dish rag, dish soap well I think it's up to the guest to utilize those things so yeah do your own dishes .

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a kitchenette is provided (airbnb, guest house or aparthotel), usually it is up to the guest to do the dishes, and usually the host offers to do the dishes with an additional fee.