# Should I wash dishes before leaving a serviced apartment?

Tags: uk, accommodation, services

I have been staying in a serviced apartment for 3 weeks and will leave soon. The service was once a week. They didn't wash dishes so far, I did myself.

I wonder if they expect me to wash dishes before leaving as well.

To be more clear, the apartment has 1 bedroom, 1 living room, 1 kitchen and 1 bathroom. Its price is a little bit higher than 3-star hotels. There is no reception, it looks like a regular apartment, so does the building.

By the way, there is a [similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/90478/room-with-kitchenette-who-does-the-dishes) on TSE, but it is for guest houses. Since I don't know if the same rules apply, I asked a new question.

Edit: I cleaned all dishes before leaving, so will not know what would be otherwise.

Comment: What does your contract say? What do the rules of the hotel say?

Comment: @JoErNanO There is "Departure Instructions" section in the booking confirmation, but nothing mentioned about that. In addition, the instructions they gave me by hand are about telephone and internet only.

Comment: I find it strange that you would ask this question. I always try to leave everywhere I stay clean and tidy. Towels and bedding will need to be changed anyway, but everything else I tidy, if only to leave a good impression.

Comment: @CannonFodder nothing wrong with making use of every service provided by a business for your money, within reason of course. I would personally wash the dishes too, but I won't blame someone for not doing so if that's what they've paid for.

Comment: @CannonFodder My question doesn't mean that I don't wash when I am not obligated. I am asking just what is usually expected. :)

Comment: Does the apartment have an automatic dishwasher?  If so, then a common rule is that you should load all dirty dishes into the dishwasher before leaving, so that the housekeeper can just start it.

Comment: @NateEldredge No, it doesn't have one.

Comment: IMO there is a difference between "washing the dishes (daily) as a matter of personal hygiene" (which I would certainly do) and "washing them to the standard I would expect to find when I first arrived at the accommodation" (which is somebody else's job).

Comment: Unless it has been explicitly stated to you that you are required to wash the dishes or else, they will hardly track you down and make you come back. That "or else" could at most be some sort of fine, but again, that would be explicitly stated *somewhere* or they'd have no legal grounds for charging you. And in case you paid in cash, they have no good way to charge you anything after the fact. In a nutshell: they have to be prepared to do the cleaning anyway, and they will do just that anyway.

Comment: @deceze, most hotel (and apartment) reservations these days are backed by a credit card. If you do not leave the hotel room or apartment as agreed on they can, and often will, charge that card.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In all apartment rental contracts I have ever read, it was mentioned you would be expected to wash the dishes you used, also on the last day.

Maybe high cost hotels have different rules, but where I rented they would not re-clean all dishes in an apartment. And I would not expect to leave dirty dishes on the side of the side of the sink.

Cleaning after you have left should be in the same range as a normal hotel room. That means that if you used a cup or glass just before leaving, you can leave that out. But not all the things used for cooking a dinner or cooked breakfast.

Answer (score 11):

Of course it simply depends on the arrangement of that facility.  But in general...

With most serviced apartments, there is a **"departure cleaning fee"**. (Often this fee is quite high.)

{People often complain about this in relation to AirBnb for example...

[image]

}

You should check if you will be paying one.

This is of course how they get the apartment spotless, for the next customer.   So, when you entered the apartment, it would be no good if only the previous person cleaned-up! Naturally, the business cleaned the flat professionally for you before your arrival.

If you paid for a car wash, there would be little point in washing the car yourself; if you paid to have your hair cut, you wouldn't cut it first!

If you're paying a (often very high) "departure cleaning fee", then perhaps just tidy up.

Cleaning the dishes is no different from cleaning anything else in the flat.  They have to completely rewash the dishes, so they are perfect for the next person, anyway. If you vacuum, clean the dishes, or clean the toilet, they have to do those things anyway.

Comment: It's also a liability.  If the next guest gets sick, the landlord will be on hook.  They can't call the previous guest back and hold them liable.

Comment: This does not answer the question: "Should I wash dishes before leaving a serviced apartment?".

Comment: heh ok @zaph, I will further clarify the final sentence.

Comment: The image you posted is unreadable, except for the headline.

Comment: I often rent a airbnb that has a rather complete set of dishes, glasses, pots and pans. There are over 30 dishes. To assume that they will all be washed after each rental—some rentals for only a day or two—is far fetched. Wash the dishes that are used, it is not that much trouble.